# How to initialise Core Data stack concurrently?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm new in iOS programming, and I'm stuck at initialising Core Data stack using GCD.
What I've tried (code from AppDelegate.m):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
bgQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.coredata.init", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    dispatch_async(bgQueue, ^{
        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc =  [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]  initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:psc];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            _mainThreadManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]  initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
            [_mainThreadManagedObjectContext setParentContext:_managedObjectContext];
            UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
            MasterViewController *controller = (MasterViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
            controller.managedObjectContext = _mainThreadManagedObjectContext;
        });
    });
}
```

However, a block within dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) doesn't executing and  application fails with an error "nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter" when other part of application is trying to use NSManagedObjectContext.

So, where should I initialise Core Data objects? Maybe in MasterViewController? Or it is possible to wait for NSManagedObjectContext initialising? Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a race condition here?  You are dispatching this block async...I would guess that something else is making use of it before the block completes.  You could always use a dispatch_semaphore to signal that the context is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear why you are doing this with GCD in this manner. I believe the most common patters is to setup the core data stack lazily, like apple do in most of their examples. You can see it in the default Xcode template for a Master/Detail project, if you check the "Use Core Data" box when creating the project.

In the AppDelegate you will find code like I pasted below. The stack is setup whenever its used. So no need to do it async with GCD.

```
 - (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

// Returns the managed object model for the application.
// If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"CoreDataStack" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

// Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
// If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"CoreDataStack.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 

         Typical reasons for an error here include:
         * The persistent store is not accessible;
         * The schema for the persistent store is incompatible with current managed object model.
         Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.


         If the persistent store is not accessible, there is typically something wrong with the file path. Often, a file URL is pointing into the application's resources directory instead of a writeable directory.

         If you encounter schema incompatibility errors during development, you can reduce their frequency by:
         * Simply deleting the existing store:
         [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil]

         * Performing automatic lightweight migration by passing the following dictionary as the options parameter:
         @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES}

         Lightweight migration will only work for a limited set of schema changes; consult "Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide" for details.

         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

I would also encourage you to have a look at this blogpost: https://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/ which discusses a way to structure your Core Data stack nicely. Its a good foundation. (see picture of suggested stack) [image]

Comment: I know this Xcode template. Is it not blocking main thread?
By the way, I've seen this article. Of course, it answers to question **how** to initialise, but doesn't answer to **where** question.

Comment: It is, see the blogpost I refered to for creating a non blocking and solid solution. Its the recommended way of structuring it afaik.

You could also have a look at Marcus. S. Zarra's book on Core Data. He also suggest this pattern, and comments on the blogpost. Its a popular book on Core Data and could be worth picking up as a newcomer to iOS as well.

Comment: I personally often setup a AppName singleton, where I keep my Core Data stack. And the singleton have references to "rootContext", "mainContext" and methods for creating new temporary background mocs.

Thats how I do it atleast, my 2c.

So I can get something like:

NSManagedObjectContext *tempContext = [FooBarProject newContextWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateConcurrencyType]; .. whenever I need a new temp context in a background process.

Comment: Today I've read an article on Cocoanetics and noted that I've missed part about NSNotification usage. I've also added some checks in my view controller and it works. Maybe I should just relax yesterday. Anyway, thanks!